# How to Set Wallpaper as Background in VS 2005 IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2005

Is there a way we can set an Image instead of plain colors as VS 2005 IDE Background

Comment: which part of the IDE? The empty workspace background?

Comment: Won't that be horribly distracting?

Comment: @Paul, not unless you have a Jessica Simpson wallpaper! :P

Comment: That's the kind of distraction I think I could live with ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the [SlickEdit free gadgets](http://www.slickedit.com/content/view/441) to render an image for my workspace background.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're going to have to write your own add-in, since this doesn't seem to be a very popular request.

Here's how to do it in VS2003: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/VSWallpaper.aspx

Here's the SDK for VS2005: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=51A5C65B-C020-4E08-8AC0-3EB9C06996F4&displaylang=en

There are lots of docs and other sample add-ins in the SDK.